# VB.NET Determine if a control shares space with another control

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that I move labels around in with the mouse.  What I'd like to do is make sure that I don't move one label into space used by another control.

Is there a better, more efficient method than what I'm using below:

```
for each c as control in me.controls
  if c.location.x > testcontrol.location.x and c.location.x < testcontrol.location.x + testcontrol.height and c.location.y > testcontrol.location.y and c.location.y < testcontrol.location.y + testcontrol.width then
     'testcontrol shares space with control c
     <do stuff>
   End if
next
```

I find the above overly clunky and hard to understand/read.  Just hoping that there's some VB magic out there that will do this much more efficiently.

From my searches, I see C# has an 'intersectswith' function, but I can't seem to find similar for VB. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311255/vb-net-collision-between-pictureboxes) shows vb using intersectwith, but I can't get that working for my stuff.  Perhaps a different version of VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add [`Bounds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bounds?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Bounds):

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
    If c.Bounds.IntersectsWith(testcontrol.Bounds) Then
         'testcontrol shares space with control c
        <do stuff>
    End If
Next
```

[`IntersectsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Drawing_Rectangle_IntersectsWith_System_Drawing_Rectangle_) isn't a method of [`Control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=netframework-4.7.1) but of [`Rectangle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Comment: D'oh.  I blame the fact that it's Monday.  Thanks MatSnow.

Comment: Glad to help. BTW It's Tuesday ;-).

Comment: FYI: It's a Monday cleverly disguised as a Tuesday up here in Canada (long weekend for us).